# PhpStorm CSS code completion with inline style

Tags: css, phpstorm, code-completion

I have a `sample.phtml` partial in a ZF 1 environment. CSS files are included in the `head.phtml` file.

If I construct in `sample.phtml` a style section like following the CSS code completion will not work, only for `text-color1`.

```
<style>
    .text-color1 {
        color: #fff;
    }
</style>
```

If I delete this style section the CSS code completion will work fine in the partial.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK it works as originally designed: if you have specific stylesheet referenced (inline or external) then code completion will offer entries from them only; if none referenced then all possible external files will be on offer.

At the moment there is no workaround *(I would think that invoking <kbd>Ctrl + Space</kbd> (or whatever you may have there for code completion popup) once again would help .. but it does not seems to do anything)*.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-7317 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on progress.